# Selector с фоном и скругленными краями

Tags: android

Есть селектор, который в качестве фона применяется в `LinearLayout`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/item_bg_blue" ></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/item_bg_blue2"></item>
</selector>
```

Фон прямоугольный. Можно ли в xml Как-нибудь скруглить края `linearLayout`? Попробовал засунуть `LinearLayout` в CardView, но на андроид 4.1 лажа получается. Т.е. если даже у `CardView` скруглить углы, то `LinerLayout` остается прямоугольным

Answer (score 0):

Создайте, например, `example_shape.xml`,

```
 <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle" >
    <solid android:color="@color/colorBackground" />


    <stroke android:width="1dip"
        android:color="@color/colorContur"/>



    <corners  android:radius="5dp" /> <--углы-->
</shape>
```

В вашем случае два на селектор.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/other_example_shape" ></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/example_shape"></item>
</selector>
```

Comment: В вопросе забыл уточнить. Что фон должен быть картинка, а не фигура.

Comment: @OVERFLOW: возможно картинку установить в foreground?